# How to make a link between Drupal and my ownCloud server?

Tags: 7

I want my documents uploaded from Drupal to be **directly** stored on my [ownCloud](http://owncloud.org) server. Drupal server and ownCloud are both installed in the **same** machine.

**Do you know how to do this type of action?**

Comment: https://www.drupal.org/project/owncloud

Answer (score 2):

As a first step you would need to share users between owncloud and drupal.

I found [this github project](https://github.com/sshtmc/owncloud-user-drupal) that appears to allow your owncloud installation to use the users from the drupal database.

Anything beyond this point requires some coding.

Assuming that the above worked and you have the user shared between the two platforms, then I expect you would need to write a drupal module with that used the [owncloud API](http://doc.owncloud.org/server/6.0/developer_manual/app/app/api/index.html) to submit a file from a drupal form. You would also need to use the owncloud api to return a list of files associated with a user.

This would be a very crude implementation, which bypassed all of drupal's file handling functionality, and relied on your own code for every interaction with owncloud (I can't find an existing module). A more advanced module would aim to use owncloud as a backend for the file system, in which case you might want to look at the patterns used in the [Droogle](http://bit.ly/1HDf5xm) or [dropbox](https://www.drupal.org/project/dropbox) modules and adapt them to the owncloud api.

Whilst writing this answer I found what looks to be an interesting discussion from drupalcon Austin entitled [Collaborative Spaces: Integrating Drupal with Google Drive, Dropbox, and more](http://bit.ly/1HDePhG). Maybe that would be of help.

Answer (score 1):

You can get your uploaded files directory in the ownCloud via the ownCloudApp [External storage support](https://doc.owncloud.org/server/8.1/admin_manual/configuration_files/external_storage_configuration_gui.html), following these steps:

1. Enable the *External storage support* App
2. Add a mount of type "Local" to the filesystem directory Drupal is uploading to.

You should, however, take care of giving access only to trustworthy users as they will be able to access/change/delete all files in that directory. A subdirectory for a certain upload case (e.g. by node type) could be sufficient. Be aware that Drupal will typically not be notified of file changes!

This solution only works if the ownCloud server is running as a user with (file system) read permissions to that directory. This should be the case if Drupal and ownCloud are running as the same user.

To prevent users from changing files, you could set suitable filesystem rights (read and not write) for the user ownCloud is running as. If that's not possible (e.g. because Drupal and ownCloud are running as the same user) you could still play with different mount types which allow setting read/write permissions.